# Nuxt3 set base directory on runtime

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've got a nuxt3 directory structure like this:

```
pages/app-one/index.vue
pages/app-two/index.vue
```

Right now I set in my `nuxt.config.ts`, the `dir` property to `app-one`, and I see `app-one` correctly.

How can I make sure I can determine the app root based on the domain name (on run-time)? I cannot push routes manually because I have a lot of dynamic routes.